# running a function over a list of lists in tidy format

Tags: r

I have downloaded data using the `edgarWebR` package.

```
library(edgarWebR)

ticker <- c('NVDA', 'GOOG')
years <- 5

company.details <- lapply(ticker, company_details)
```

I have two lists and I am trying to apply a function to each of the lists:

```
filing_doc <- function(href) {
  sapply(href, function(x) {
    filing_documents(x) %>%
      filter( type == "10-K" ) %>% select(href) }) %>%
    unlist(recursive = TRUE, use.names = FALSE)
}
```

I apply the function:

```
company.reports <- company.details$filings %>%
  filter(type == "10-K") %>%
  slice(1:years) %>% 
  mutate(doc.href = filing_doc(href),
         mdlink = paste0("[Filing Link](", href, ")"),
         reportLink = paste0("[10-K Link](", doc.href, ")")) %>%
  select(filing_date, accession_number, mdlink, reportLink, href, doc.href)
```

However this will not work since I am trying to apply this over a list of 2.

The following works

```
company.reports <- company.details[[1]]$filings %>%
  filter(type == "10-K") %>%
  slice(1:years) %>% 
  mutate(doc.href = filing_doc(href),
         mdlink = paste0("[Filing Link](", href, ")"),
         reportLink = paste0("[10-K Link](", doc.href, ")")) %>%
  select(filing_date, accession_number, mdlink, reportLink, href, doc.href)
```

Where I have just added the [[1]] to the first line. My question is how can I apply this same code over multiple lists - I run into errors using `lapply` and pipe functions.

Ultimately I would like to have the same output as the last piece of code but filled with information for all of the companies in `ticker`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this solution:

```
company.reports <-
  company.details %>%
  map(
    ~.x$filings %>%
      filter(type == "10-K") %>%
      slice(1:years) %>% 
      mutate(doc.href = filing_doc(href),
             mdlink = paste0("[Filing Link](", href, ")"),
             reportLink = paste0("[10-K Link](", doc.href, ")")) %>%
      select(filing_date, accession_number, mdlink, reportLink, href, doc.href)
  )
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you briefly explain the functionality of the map function here? I see it used often.

Comment: The best explanation of `map` can be found here: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/iteration.html.